# What do I use to build a robust referrer tracking system?

Tags: php, http, redirect, tracking, referrer

I've just started working for a client using facebook ads, and the problem they are having is that their logs don't match facebook's claimed click-through-rate.

I'm *not* asking anyone to code this for me, but just a pointer in the right direction.

Basically I know the referrer is potentially unreliable, FB say as much themselves, so I guess it'll be something like this:

1. Ad with unique url to intermediate page (this is the bit I'm interested in - what's best? php script to handle incoming or URL with appended values or other?)
2. intermediate page records visit into database
3. Intermediate page redirects user to main page

Does anyone have any examples or experience to help me answer this?

**Edit** Since I posted this I've been talking to a few poeple, and taking the comments onboard. What I found was that there is a school of thought that the time that a page loads may affect if someone is recorded in the access logs or not.

The suggestion goes "step 5 is the problem":

1. User clicks
2. behind ad is FB intermediate URL not your URL
3. On landing at FB Click is recorded and user redirected to your URL
4. User arrives at your server, page is sent
5. User receives page

But as we are surely talking almost virtually imperceptable time between step 1 and 4 it does seem possible to set up a check that would not fail to match FBs results more closely a dummy page would take no time to load at all especially if all it does is redirect.

I'll post my findings.

Comment: i guess a simple answer will be: i agree

Comment: If the page people are visiting is uncacheable, you could just ensure that the page request is logged and check your webserver logs. Don't put the URL the same as the website frontpage, put something like `example.com/?ref=fb` and make this page redirect back to homepage and the just check webserver log for this page requests (this is the fastest way).

Comment: @dresende the point I think is that they have a question mark over fb tracking/billing being accurate *because* the webserver logs do not match. If you read Facebook help on this they even confirm this as a possibility. I think my customer is looking for something independent from the logs.

Comment: You have other possibilities, but at the very minimum if you have logs on, the counting must be the same. I was talking about uncacheable banner link so ISP's don't cache it and another user using the same ISP won't use the ISP's cache instead of going to you. I don't see any other option, considering Facebook does not fake clicks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known mystery using facebook ads.

Facebook says - You're website / page / app had 1000 clicks... every way we track it (our own tracking, raw logs, google analytics) shows we had maybe 300 at most.

Try getting an answers from facebook. We did, and with no luck.

The only thing that really matters is conversion, and if it makes sense to keep paying for FB ads.

One thing we did do was to reduce our Bid to the lowest possible value without causing them to stop.

Other friends of mine swear by CPM rather than CPC on facebook, although we didn't see much benefit.

At the end of the day... make sure your conversion numbers are good enough to pay facebook.

Still smells a bit to me though.

Comment: agreed conversion is the important factor, but you know clients, they want to know what they are paying for, and if there's a sniff of inconsistency.... In any case I'm not doubting FB, and I hope I can build something that gives results that match their data. It's easy enough to test.

Comment: it is a client base error. if the user clicks the ads in the facebook then FB records it as click/viewed (please note the FB records this with delay so offline clicks are also counted) but in reality in the client side the data/view is interrupted because the client close it before the browser can request for the website resources please note about DNS too and client having slow internet connection or your domain not found by client dns server those are just few factors.

Answer (score 0):

If your customer does not trust facebook, they should ask facebook, not you because there is not much of what you can do about that social problem.

Comment: The customer tried this, and Facebook suggested that they ask a developer to build a tracking system. Again FB are quite clear about this in the documentation.

Comment: Well, then find a developer that is fit in coding a tracking system. Maybe others have the same problem, too and you can start a project.

Comment: @T9b - This is one of those cases where you really need a tracking mechanism (cookie or GET unique ID, most likely) to determine something that's *reasonably reliable*. If your customer isn't knowledgeable about the accuracy of the methods they're relying on, and the benefit of that metric, you're going to have problems.

Comment: The main question was to ask if anyone had experience of having to test FBs results through tracking. The consensus online appears to be that FB results do not match the traffic, and from a technical perspective the time between click and visit must generally be very small, and it's difficult to see where that click can get lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you could control the banner image (not being static on the Facebook side), you could kind of generate a unique number and save it on a database. Then, when people click on the banner, that unique number would be on the link and you could check if the number was generated or not.

This way, you would know for sure the number of banners displayed and banners clicked and facebook could not just increase click count. Perhaps that's what where the missing clicks are... (banners displayed/banners clicked).